# Next item in foreach SMARTY

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I do slider on the website. On one slide I have two div. The data displayed on the SMARTY.

Slider div's

```
{foreach $slider as $sliderr}
    <div id="sliderBox">
<div id="showcase" class="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content">
{$sliderr.img}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content">
                {$sliderr.img} // ?? I need img+1
            </div>
        </div>  
</div>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

I need the next record from the table slider. How to read the next record SMARTY in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
{foreach from=$slider key=i item=sliderr}
    <div id="sliderBox">
<div id="showcase" class="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content">
{$sliderr.img}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content">
                {$slider[{$i+1}]}
            </div>
        </div>  
</div>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I think it's `{$slider[$i+1]}`

Comment: yeah could be! I have had no possibility to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this. It can operate with infinite slider loop.

```
{foreach from = $slider key = f item = product}
```

Name of next slide:

```
{if isset($slider[$f+1])}{$slider[$f+1].name}{else}{$slider[0].name}{/if}
```

Name of previous slide:

```
{if isset($slider[$f-1])}{$slider[$f-1].name}{else}{$slider[($slider|count)-1].name}{/if}

{/foreach}
```